# Unable to connect peers using multipeer conectivity Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

My swift code does not connect one to each other.
The simple objective is to send a image.

```
import UIKit
```

import MultipeerConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

```
var peerID: MCPeerID!
var mcSession: MCSession!
var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
@IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.none)
    mcSession.delegate = self
    joinSession(action: UIAlertAction.init())
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {

}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL, withError error: Error?) {

}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state {
    case MCSessionState.connected:
        print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.notConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    }
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.img.image = image
        }
    }
}


func joinSession(action: UIAlertAction!) {
    print("batata")
    let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-kb", session: mcSession)
    mcBrowser.delegate = self
    present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
    print("batatinha")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

second code

import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

```
var peerID: MCPeerID!
var mcSession: MCSession!
var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.none)
    mcSession.delegate = self as MCSessionDelegate
    startHosting(action: UIAlertAction.init())
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {

}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL, withError error: Error?) {

}
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}


func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {

    switch state {
    case MCSessionState.connected:
        print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.notConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    }
}

func sendImage(img: UIImage) {
     print("baby")
    if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        print("baby1")
        if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
            print("baby2")
            do {
                try mcSession.send(imageData, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func teste(_ sender: Any) {
    print("hey")
    let img = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "triangle.png")
    self.img.image = img
    sendImage(img: img)
    print(mcSession.connectedPeers)

}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

}



func startHosting(action: UIAlertAction!) {
    print("lololo")
    mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "hws-kb", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
    mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem,but i solved it by using service type hws-connect.